# pandas: one hot encoding - how to get one hot encoding if the col contains csv values

Tags: python, encoding, data-science

Say the data is like

```
d = {'col1': ['a,b', 'b', 'c,d', 'a,c'], 'col2': [3, 4, 5, 6]}
s = pd.DataFrame(d)
    col1    col2
0   a,b      3
1   b        4
2   c,d      5
3   a,c      6
```

Would like to one hot encode the col1. As follows:

```
    a   b   c   d
0   1   1   0   0   
1   0   1   0   0   
2   0   0   1   1
3   1   0   1   0
```

Thanks

Comment: Heads up: This isn't a one-hot encoding. One-hot means one out of a set of possible options is 'hot' (has the value '1') while the rest are off (has the value '0'). One-hot means: this record can hold one and only one of the following options. You're looking for a binary vector representation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that in 4 lines of code with list and dict comprehensions (or 3 if you collapse the 3rd and the 4th :) )

```
# 1. Create a list of lists, where each sublist contains the characters
#    contained in the columnd    
separated_data = [[sub_el for sub_el in el.strip(',') if ',' not in sub_el] 
                    for el in s['col1']]
# separated_data is [['a', 'b'], ['b'], ['c', 'd'], ['a', 'c']]


# 2. (optional) find the set of keys contained in your dataframe,
#        if you don't already know that
keys = set([key for sublist in separated_data for key in sublist])
# keys is {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'}


# 3. Create a dictionary, where the each character is a key and each value
#     is a list. The n-th value of the list says 1 if the character is
#     contained in the n-th row, 0 otherwise
columns = {key: [1 if key in sublist else 0 for sublist in separated_data] 
                for key in keys}
              for key in keys]
# columns is {'a': [1, 0, 0, 1], 'b': [1, 1, 0, 0], 'c': [0, 0, 1, 1], 'd': [0, 0, 1, 0]}


# 4. Your dataframe
onehot_dataframe = pd.Dataframe(columns)
# onehot_dataframe is:
#    a  b  c  d
# 0  1  1  0  0
# 1  0  1  0  0
# 2  0  0  1  1
# 3  1  0  1  0
```

Comment: Thank you! Much appreciated. I was not clear in my qs that a, b, c were not characters but represented strings e.g. itemname1, itemname2, itemname3.  So I had to modify your solution a bit to change separated_data creation to separated_data = [el.split(',') for el in s['col1']]